# DirectWrite: Use Different Font for Latin and Complex Script

Tags: c++, fonts, direct2d, directwrite

I use `CreateTextLayout` and `CreateTextFormat` to draw text with DirectWrite (C++), the text is mixed Hebrew/English, is there a way to use a different font/font size for the Latin and Hebrew characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling `IDWriteFont::HasCharacter` to build text ranges inside which all characters use the same font (the hebrew or the latin one).

If that text range uses the hebrew font, I call `textLayout->SetFontSize` on it to increase the font size.

This amounts to anticipating the font callback `DirectWrite` will do, which is automatic and cannot be customized.

Comment: That approach works. Just be to treat surrogate pairs as a whole character (and maybe skip variation selectors, e.g. U+FE00..FE0F). Note IDWriteTextLayout on Windows 8.1 supports customization of font fallback via IDWriteFontFallback, creating an IDWriteFontFallbackBuilder, calling AddMapping with the Hebrew Unicode ranges, AddMappings with the system font collection as a catch all, and then SetFontFallback on layout.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `IDWriteTextFormat` using `CreateTextFormat`, you can pass the name of the font family in the first parameter and you can change the size of the font in sixth parameter.

You can get the `CreateTextFormat` parameters from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_fonts) is a list of Microsoft Windows font families, you will find ones in Latin and Hebrew there.

Comment: Well yes I know, the problem is that the long text string that I pass to CreateTextLayout has both Latin and Complex (Hebrew) characters, like "Hello שלום Hello שלום", and I would like the unique textLayout->Draw call to draw the Latin characters of that string with one font/font size and the Hebrew characters with another...

Comment: @BanK I'm not familiar with any built into direct2d other then you doing it manually.

Comment: OK, the text is entered by the user who can mix hebrew and english in any way. I think there is a font fallback quirk, the fonts I want to use only have hebrew characters (and others like 1234567890 and ()[] ' " etc) and are much smaller for the same font size than regular fonts. DirectWrite automatically falls back to a standard font for the latin characters, so the hebrew characters are tiny and unreadable compared to the latin ones. I want to tell DirectWrite to use a different font size in case of fallback.